# Decoding a Base64 file with org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream

Tags: java, stream, base64, apache-commons

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I've got an strange issue with `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream`: it gives me exactly the same original Base64 encoded byte stream.

The used code is:

```
  InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(
                           new File("/tmp/inputFile")));
  try
  {
    File decodedFile = new File("/tmp/file.dec");
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(decodedFile));
    try
    {
      Base64InputStream b64is = new Base64InputStream(is); 
      try
      {
        byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
        int count;
        while ((count = is.read(buff)) > 0)
        {
          os.write(buff, 0, count);
        }
      } finally
      {
        b64is.close();
      }
    } finally
    {
      os.close();
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    is.close();
  }
```

If the `inputFile` contains a Base64 encoded string (as, for example `0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOwADAP7/C`, after executing this code, `/tmp/file.dec` contains exactly the same string...

Anybody knows why it is not being decoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the wrong stream. This

```
while ((count = is.read(buff)) > 0)
```

Should be

```
while ((count = b64is.read(buff)) > 0)
```

Comment: Damm!!! It is true!!! Thankyou very much!!! I guess I need some sleep ;-)